# Numerical integration of a numerical integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a complicated function $f(x)$ whose analytical form does not exist for the following integral
$$g(x)=\int_0^x\mathrm{d}x'\,f(x'). $$
I finally need to evaluate the following integral 
$$\int_0^a\mathrm{d}x\,g(x)~,$$
where $a$ is some finite real number like 1000. 
Therefore, essentially I need two NIntegrate. However, NIntegrate needs finite integration limit, not some abstract $x$. How do I deal with this problem?

Comment: `NIntegrate[f[y], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, x}]`?

Comment: @J.M., There is a spelling mistake in `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @J.M. That does not work: In[25]:= NIntegrate[Exp[-x], {x, 0, y}, {y, 0, 10}]

Out[25]= NIntegrate[Exp[-x], {x, 0, y}, {y, 0, 10}]

Comment: @titanium, look at my code carefully again, and note the order of the second and third arguments.

Comment: Can you post your code please? Can you show the function f(x)?

Comment: For this case, you might use the identity `Integrate[(a - x) f[x], {x, 0, a}] == 
 Integrate[f[x], {y, 0, a}, {x, 0, y}]`

Answer (score 2):

This can be written down as the parametric iterated integral
$$I(a)=\int_0^a\left( \int_0^x f(y)\mathrm dy\right) \mathrm dx$$
NIntegrate supports the syntax

```
NIntegrate[f,{x,xm,xM},{y,ym,yM}]
```

(where $x_m,x_M$ are the bounds of the outer integral, $y_m,y_M$ of the inner one) to compute this kind of integrals. This means that you can evaluate your result numerically through the following line of code:

```
I[a_]:=NIntegrate[f[y],{x,0,a},{y,0,x}]
```

Just substitute your favourite $f(y)$ inside to obtain the result: mine is

```
In: I1[a_]:=NIntegrate[1,{x,0,a},{y,0,x}];
In: I1[1]
Out: 0.5
```